# How to check SQL Server Database compatibility after sp_dbcmptlevel is deprecated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, compatibility

According to BOL (SQL Server Books Online) on [`sp_dbcmptlevel`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178653.aspx),

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. Use ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level instead.

Now, the only TSQL way I know of checking database compatibility is through `sp_dbcmptlevel`.
As far as I know, [`ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) is just for **setting** the compatibility level, not getting info.

How should one to get compatibility level without using GUI?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
select name, compatibility_level , version_name = 
CASE compatibility_level
    WHEN 65  THEN 'SQL Server 6.5'
    WHEN 70  THEN 'SQL Server 7.0'
    WHEN 80  THEN 'SQL Server 2000'
    WHEN 90  THEN 'SQL Server 2005'
    WHEN 100 THEN 'SQL Server 2008/R2'
    WHEN 110 THEN 'SQL Server 2012'
    WHEN 120 THEN 'SQL Server 2014'
    WHEN 130 THEN 'SQL Server 2016'
    WHEN 140 THEN 'SQL Server 2017'
    WHEN 150 THEN 'SQL Server 2019'
    WHEN 160 THEN 'SQL Server 2022'
    ELSE 'new unknown - '+CONVERT(varchar(10),compatibility_level)
END
from sys.databases
```

Comment: I would add that you can work this out by opening SQL Server Profiler and seeing what Management Studio does. I just had a look and inside a rather long and badly formatted query it also uses sys.databases

Comment: `select cmptlevel from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name = db_name()` for SQL2000+, not sure when this will go away.

Answer (score 19):

```
select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name ='myDB'
```

Answer (score 7):

Thought this would be useful here...

```
65 = SQL Server 6.5
70 = SQL Server 7.0
80 = SQL Server 2000
90 = SQL Server 2005
100 = SQL Server 2008/R2
110 = SQL Server 2012
120 = SQL Server 2014
130 = SQL Server 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

How to check SQL Server Database compatibility

```
       SELECT compatibility_level  as [Current compatibility_level] FROM
         sys.databases WHERE name = 'Database Name';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add the answer from msdn:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'AdventureWorks2012';
GO
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794.aspx

Comment: it says that i do not have sys.databases in my database