# Incorrect syntax near OFFSET command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Why this doesn't work and gives me a "Incorrect syntax near offset command" error

```
SELECT o.orderdate, o.orderid, o.empid, o.custid FROM Sales.Orders o
ORDER BY o.orderdate, o.orderid
OFFSET 50 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY;
```

I am using SQL Server Express 2014

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check the database compatibility level.
`OFFSET` was added in SQL Server 2012, so if your database is in 2008 compatibility mode, this keyword is not available.

[View or Change the Compatibility Level of a Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794.aspx)

In T-SQL you can check it like this:

```
 USE AdventureWorks2012;  
 GO  

 SELECT compatibility_level  
 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'AdventureWorks2012';  
 GO
```

Here is a list of compatibility levels taken from [How to check SQL Server Database compatibility after sp_dbcmptlevel is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501596/how-to-check-sql-server-database-compatibility-after-sp-dbcmptlevel-is-deprecate):

```
 65 - SQL Server 6.5
 70 - SQL Server 7.0
 80 - SQL Server 2000
 90 - SQL Server 2005
100 - SQL Server 2008/R2
110 - SQL Server 2012
120 - SQL Server 2014
130 - SQL Server 2016
140 - SQL Server 2017
```

---

Besides, Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse do not support `OFFSET` clause, as can be seen from the docs of the [`ORDER BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause:

> ```
> -- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  
>
> ORDER BY order_by_expression  
>     [ COLLATE collation_name ]   
>     [ ASC | DESC ]   
>     [ ,...n ]   
> [ <offset_fetch> ]  
>
> <offset_fetch> ::=  
> {   
>     OFFSET { integer_constant | offset_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS }  
>     [  
>       FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } {integer_constant | fetch_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS } ONLY  
>     ]  
> }
> ```

> ```
> -- Syntax for Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse  
>
> [ ORDER BY   
>     {  
>     order_by_expression   
>     [ ASC | DESC ]   
>     } [ ,...n ]   
> ]
> ```

Comment: My compatibility level is 130 (SQL Server 2016) but still see the same error. This is an SQL Server DW instance on Azure if that makes any difference.

Comment: @shashwat, the docs for [ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause show the syntax for normal SQL Server and for Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse. DW version doesn't support `OFFSET` clause.

Comment: I changed the compatibility level. But the syntax is incorrect too. The proper syntax is OFFSET 1 ROWS 
 FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY; I had an error for the information on this page https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155998/get-second-highest-value-in-a-table.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that I was attempting to use `OFFSET` on a view, but wasn't joining.

Problematic query:

```
declare @PageSize int = 25;
declare @PageNumber int = 1;

with countCte as 
(
    select count(*) as TotalCount from vw_viewName vn
    where 1=1
)
select * from vw_viewName vn
cross join countCte cou
where 1=1
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Adding an `order by` fixed the problem:

```
where 1=1
order by vn.ID desc
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Op has clearly an order by clause there. Not sure why you gave this answer.

Comment: I gave this answer for programmers other than OP searching for possible solutions.

Comment: then your first bit of code is still irrelevant. Anyways.

Answer (score 1):

To add a possible common cause for this error (though not the OP case):

The `ORDER BY` clause is missing.