# 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like below.

```
SELECT FORMAT (Submitted_time,'dd-MM-yyyy h:mm tt')
FROM header
```

And I get the expected output on some of the latest SQL Server as :

```
27-07-2020 9:15 AM
```

But when executing same query on some other SQL Server machine, it throws an exception

> 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Update the older servers to be on a supported version. `FORMAT` was introduced a few versions ago; all currently supported versions have it.

Comment: `FORMAT` isnt a particularly performant function though, you're better off with `CONVERT` and style codes.

Comment: Just avoid running `FORMAT` on millions of rows and you won't notice the difference. If you are formatting something for human consumption likely the number of rows will be small anyway

Answer (score 4):

The `FORMAT` function was introduced with `SQL Server 2012` and as pointed in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it is available in `all supported versions`.

You are either running it in older version or the [compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1501638/1080354) of the database is set to earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Not all SQL Server versions FORMAT function work
You can use convert as below:

```
DECLARE @Submitted_time datetime 

SET @Submitted_time= GETDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),@Submitted_time , 121)
```

Output

```
2020-10-07 09:11:07.923
```

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have a pre-2012 version of SQL Server or a compatibility level set to an earlier version.  You may be able to construct the string that you want using:

```
select replace(convert(varchar(255), getdate(), 105) + ' ' + right(convert(varchar(255), getdate()), 7), '  ', ' ')
```